# Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure or call argument

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm attempting to run a macro and keep getting a "run-time error '5': invalid procedure or call argument." Nothing has changed to the file nor the macro since I last used it, but I did get a new laptop. I'm not sure if this has to do with permissions in my excel or if in fact the macro is broken and needs to be fixed.

```
Sub SS_Cleanup()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        Sheets("report").Select
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Range("H:H").Activate
    Selection.Replace What:="Global Equity, benchmarked to the MSCI ACWI", _
        Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="ESG High Conviction, benchmarked to the MSCI ACWI", _
        Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="International Conviction, benchmarked to the MSCI ACWI", _
        Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:= _
        "No Animal Testing (Medical/Pharma Allowed) Strategy benchmarked to the S", _
        Replacement:= _
        "No Animal Testing (Medical/Pharma Allowed) Strategy benchmarked to the S&P 1500" _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
        :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:= _
        "Gifting", _
        Replacement:= _
        "Not Applicable" _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
        :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        
    Dim i, n As Integer
    Dim ProductHolder, Product As String
    Dim ProductName As String
            

            i = 2
          

    Do While Workbooks("SS Data Converter.xlsm").Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
            

            'enters the product in last column
            ProductHolder = ""
            Product = ""
            ProductName = ""
            

            ProductHolder = Workbooks("SS Data Converter.xlsm").Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 8)
            If ProductHolder <> "" And ProductHolder <> "Not Applicable" And ProductHolder <> "Jointly Managed" Then
                Product = Right(ProductHolder, Len(ProductHolder) - InStr(ProductHolder, "S&") + 1)
                **ProductName = Left(ProductHolder, InStr(ProductHolder, "Strategy") - 2)**
            End If
            Select Case Product
            Case "S&P 1500"
```

The bold text above is what is saying is a problem with the macro. I haven't attempted to fix it but instead research the root cause. Thanks.

Comment: The fourth line from the bottom is what I was referencing at the end of my question as the root problem.  ProductName = Left(ProductHolder, InStr(ProductHolder, "Strategy") - 2)

Comment: Likely `InStr(ProductHolder, "Strategy") - 2` results in an invalid value (e.g. negative)